# Custom use case environment that can break across columns

Tags: tables, macros, environments, tabularx

I created a custom environment to separate the semantics from design and formatting of use case tables. Everything works fine except the `tabularx` environment is unable to break across columns which creates nasty looking areas of white space when several (especially longer) use cases follow right after one another. Is there any way I can enable them to break across columns?

[image: MWE 1]
[image: MWE 2]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multicol,enumitem,blindtext}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[2][DarkBlue]{\textbf{\large\sffamily\color{#1} #2}}

\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{usecase}
    \noindent\tabularx{\linewidth}{lX}
    \rowcolor{gray!20}\tabhead{Case~\theusecase} & \tabhead[DarkGreen]{#1}\\
    \toprule
    }
    {\bottomrule\endtabularx\medskip}

\newcommand{\actor}[1]{Actor & #1\\\midrule}

\newcommand{\precondition}[1]{Needs & #1\\\midrule}

\newcommand{\mainpath}[1]{
    Path & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\blindenumerate[20]
    \end{minipage}\\}

\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}



\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{Casimir}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

### Update

New implementation with inspiration from David Carlisle.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{multicol,enumitem,blindtext}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\uchead}[2][DarkBlue]{\textbf{\large\sffamily\color{#1} #2}}

\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{usecase}
    \noindent\colorbox{gray!20}{%
       \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{%
         \uchead{Case~\theusecase}~~\uchead[DarkGreen]{#1}}}\par
    \hrule}
    {\bigskip}

\newlength\lcol\setlength{\lcol}{1.2cm}
\newcommand{\ucentry}[1]{\noindent\strut\makebox[\lcol][l]{\textbf{#1}}}

\newcommand{\actor}[1]{%
    \ucentry{Actor} #1\hrule}

\newcommand{\precondition}[1]{%
    \ucentry{Needs} #1\hrule}

\newcommand{\mainpath}[1]{%
    \ucentry{Path}
    \vspace{-\dimexpr\parskip+\baselineskip}%
    \setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=\dimexpr\lcol+\fboxsep} #1\smallskip\hrule}

\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}



\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{Casimir}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{\blindenumerate[9]}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{\blindenumerate[9]}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{\blindenumerate[9]}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{\blindenumerate[9]}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{\blindenumerate[9]}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{\blindenumerate[9]}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{\blindenumerate[9]}
\end{usecase}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that look like lists are usually better set as lists than tables, then they break naturally.

You could fiddle a bit more with the spacing but:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,multicol,enumitem,blindtext}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[2][DarkBlue]{\textbf{\large\sffamily\color{#1} #2}}

\newcounter{usecase}
\newenvironment{usecase}[1]{
    \refstepcounter{usecase}
    \colorbox{gray!20}{%
       \makebox[2cm][l]{\tabhead{Case~\theusecase}}%
       \hspace{6pt}%
       \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-3cm-6pt-2\fboxsep]{%
         \tabhead[DarkGreen]{#1}}}\par
    \hrule}
    {\hrule\medskip}

\newcommand{\actor}[1]{%
   \par
   \makebox[2cm][l]{\strut Actor}
       \hspace{6pt}%
   \mbox{#1}\par\hrule}

\newcommand{\precondition}[1]{%
   \par
   \makebox[2cm][l]{\strut Needs}
       \hspace{6pt}%
   \mbox{#1}\par\hrule}


\newcommand{\mainpath}[1]{%
   \par
   \makebox[2cm][l]{\strut Path}
    \par
   \nobreak
   \vspace{-\dimexpr\parskip+\baselineskip}%
    \setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=2cm}%
   \blindenumerate[20]
  }

\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}



\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{Casimir}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext

\subsection{First Subsection}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\begin{usecase}{Some use case}
    \actor{Some actor}
    \precondition{User logged in}
    \mainpath{}
\end{usecase}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion! I adapted your implementation made some changes (see my updated question). A few questions remain, though: 1. Can I set `\parskip` to zero only inside an environment so that I don't have to include a `\noindent` on every new line? 2. How can I prevent the `\hrule`s from breaking to the next column, even if at the very end of a column? 3. How come the `\hrule` below the `enumerate` environment is right on the baseline (unless I include a `\smallskip`)?

Comment: 4. How can I make text break onto new lines if it doesn't fit into the use case header?

Comment: @Casimir replace the `\makebox[length]{stuff}` by `\parbox[t]{length}{\raggedright stuff}` in the definitions

Comment: yes just `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` inside the environment. Add more `\nobreak` here and there (or put all the heading lines into a minipage) or ...

Comment: Weird, I'm pretty sure I had tried `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` to no effect. Now it works, though. Thanks for your help!